# Cannot resolve symbol inflater

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm trying to implement Google Maps into a fragment, but I'm getting an error that's telling me I can't resolve my inflater or container on this line:

`rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_layout, container, false);`.

Could it possibly be anything to do with my Layout File? Here's my Java Fragment:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


    public class menu_1_fragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        View rootview;
        @Nullable

        @Override
        protected View onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu2_layout, container, false);
            return rootview;
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title("Sydney")
                    .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
                    .position(sydney));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You haven't defined `container` _or_ `inflater`... That should be clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your method from :

```
protected View onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

to

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

also 
delete the super call